# "No similarly named formulae found" when trying to install MongoDB on macOS

Tags: mongodb, macos, homebrew

I'm trying to install MongoDB server on macOS Big Sur using brew, I'm following the documentation on the official mongo website.
I run the following command:

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
```

after that, I run:

```
brew install mongodb-community@4.4
```

but I got the following error:

> Error: No similarly named formulae found.
> Error: No available formula with the name "mongosh" (dependency of mongodb/brew/mongodb-community).
> It was migrated from mongodb/brew to homebrew/core.

Comment: Have you tried tapping homebrew/core and installing mongosh manually?

Comment: @tao sorry it was by mistake, i re-open it. you can put the answer there, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

For me `homebrew-core` was not tapped properly.

```
 brew doctor


Warning: Homebrew/homebrew-core was not tapped properly! Run:
  rm -rf "/opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core"
  brew tap homebrew/core

Warning: Some taps are not on the default git origin branch and may not receive
updates. If this is a surprise to you, check out the default branch with:
  git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) checkout master
```

We need to remove and tap homebrew/core again.

```
rm -rf "/opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core"
brew tap homebrew/core
```

After this we need to tap mongodb/brew

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
```

And then install mongodb-community

```
brew install mongodb-community
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

As the error message shows, you need to first install `mongosh`(https://github.com/mongodb-js/mongosh#readme).

Steps:

1. `brew update`
2. `brew install mongosh`
3. `brew install mongodb-community` .

Should fix your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Steps:

1. `brew untap mongodb/brew`
2. `brew tap mongodb/brew`
3. `brew install mongodb-community`

fix my problem.

Comment: Refusing to untap mongodb/brew because it contains the following installed formulae or casks:

Answer (score 2):

Run this command in terminal:

```
rm -fr $(brew --repo homebrew/core)
```

Then try:

```
 brew install mongosh
```

or

```
brew install mongodb-community@4.4
```

It work perfectly

Comment: He is asking it for mongodb-community@6.0. So the first step will be what you mentioned in your answer, but the second step will be brew install mongodb-community@6.0 or whatever the current version is.

Comment: if he want latest version then he can use or if specific version then you are absolutely right ill update my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove tap by running `brew untap mongodb/brew`.

Then you can run `brew install mongodb-community@4.4` and it will install from the core homebrew tap, where the package now lives.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was linked to the homebrew core being missing as per https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/1512

steps: run the command

`brew config`

if you get
`Core tap HEAD: (none)` in the body, then likely you had the same issue as me. Run the command

```
brew tap homebrew/core
```

You can then go back to the installation steps

```
brew tap mongodb/brew

brew install mongodb-community@6.0
```

And everything should install correctly (it did for me anyway).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the mongosh formula that MongoDB Community 4.4 depends on was migrated from the mongodb/brew tap to the homebrew/core tap. You can try installing the mongosh formula from the homebrew/core tap first before installing MongoDB Community 4.4.

To do this, run the following command:

```
brew install mongosh
```

Then, try installing MongoDB Community 4.4 again using the following command:

```
brew install mongodb-community@4.4
```

This should install MongoDB Community 4.4 and any dependencies it requires, including the mongosh formula.

Not the latest version is 6.0. So you should use this command for it.

```
brew install mongodb-community@6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same problem on my mac running Intel Processor.

I first run

```
rm -fr $(brew --repo homebrew/core)
```

then

```
brew tap homebrew/core
```

then

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
```

then installed it

```
brew install mongodb-community@6.0
```

This worked for me.